# Passing Flow variables into apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, callout, split

I have passed a string in exactly this format with a ',' delimiter (**a014K000001W1wqQAC,000410001006672,500,34567**) from a flow to an invocable APEX method.

```
    public class obuTopUpTrailhead {
    @InvocableMethod
    
    public static void invokeapexcallout(list<String> obuDetails){
      for (string s : obuDetails){
         // Loop body
         }  
       }
     }
```

In the APEX class invokable method, how can I split comma delimited String and assign them to public class variables?
This is what I am looking to perform:
Var 1 = a014K000001W1wqQAC
Var 2 = 000410001006672
Var 3 = 500
Var 4 = 34567

Thanks in advance for every bit of help!

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much already answered it; you just use the split method.

```
  for (string s : obuDetails){
    String[] parts = s.split(',');
    var1 = parts[0];
    var2 = parts[1];
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes got it working :-)